# Object does not exist - Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, error-handling, mlab

**Error:** I'm having an error of "*Cannot set property 'username' of null.*" It seems like the error happens when I try to find the currently logged in user with "*User.findOne*"

**Question:** Why would req.user be found but then the code not be able to find the currently logged in user? What should I change to make sure it does find the logged in user which I know exists.

To access this route a user **must** be logged in:

```
   router.post("/updateAccount", function(req, res){
    
    if (req.user) {
    
    User.findOne({username: req.body.currentUser}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
    return done(err);
    }
    
    user.username = req.body.username;

    ...});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try async await

```
router.post("/updateAccount", async function(req, res){

if (req.user) {

await User.findOne({username: req.body.currentUser}, function(err, user) {
if (err) {
return done(err);
}

user.username = req.body.username;

...});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using BodyParser in you main server

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I can confirm BodyParser is working as expected.